# Pseudocode for an array search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

The question:

"Write an algorithm that given an array A and an integer value k it returns the value true if there are two different integers in A that sum to k, and it returns false otherwise."

My pseudocode:

Input: array A of size n with value k

Output: true if two different integers in A sum to k, false otherwise

```
Algorithm ArraySum(A, n, k)
for (i=0, i<n, i++)
    for (j=i+1, j<n, j++)
        if (A[i]+A[j]=k)
            return true
return false
```

Have I written this algorithm correctly? Are there any mistakes I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two different integers means `A[i], A[j]` where `i != j` rather than `A[i] != A[j]`, your pseudocode is correct.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Each position in the array contains a unique integer. For instance, the example array given was [4|7|3|9|2|1|5]. We are meant to compare/sum the contents of the array, not the positions.

Comment: @user41419 Marcus is right to mention the comparison of positions. However, in your algorithm, that comparison would always evaluate to true, which is why it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions in my mind regarding the problem

**First Solution**

1.Make an empty hash
2.Mark all number in array in hash

```
 for each i (Array A){
        hash[i] = 1;
    }
```

3.Just run an `O(n)` loop

```
for each i (Array A)
    if(  hash[ k - i ] ) 
        print "solution i and k-i"
```

That will give you `O(n)` complexity

**Second Solution**

1.Sort Array
2.Run an `O(n)` loop over the sorted Array

```
for each i (Array A)
    binary_search( Array, k - i); [log n operation]
```

That will give you `O(n logn)` complexity.

Comment: I think second solution is more convenient.

Comment: to keep lees memory, Yes. second method will not required any extra memory spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is looks like as some case of [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

For your case (only two numbers), may be will be better to sort your array to reduce number of comparision (A[i]+A[j]=k).

For example:

```
you have sorted array [1 3 5 8 10 12 14 20 50 60 100]
sum of two numbers must be equal to 30
```

Then you can write

```
 while(a[i] <= 30) {
   while(a[i] + a[j] <= 30) {
    // ...
    i++;
    j++;
   } 
 }
```